# How to get the millisecond part of current time?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I'm trying to record an event at its happening time by accuracy of milliseconds. Below is my code:

```
        NSDate * now = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
        NSString *timeString = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:now];
```

However, the results are as this:

```
45:11.3
```

It looks like time record has been rounded to 0.1 second, while all the second and third decimal accuracy is lost. Can anyone suggest where the problem is and how I can get the millisecond information?

Thank you all!

Paul

Comment: Hi Paul, try this format [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss:SSS"]; should work for you...

Comment: Code works fine. Voting to close as non-reproducible.

Comment: Laky's suggestion actually works, thanks also go to matt for your testing out your code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine for me. Here it is (in Swift):

```
let f = NSDateFormatter()
f.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss.SSS"
let timeString = f.stringFromDate(NSDate()) // "20:26:19.118"
```

You do not show the code by which you *read* the resulting `timeString` but perhaps the fault lies in how you are doing that. It is odd that the Hour part is missing from your output too.